# Exporting Access Database into MySql through php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a Database in MS Access and I want to export this database into mysql through php script.

It's quite easy to import csv file into mysql through script but how can I export my Access Database into csv file from php script?  Then I will be able to simply import that csv file into mysql database.

Answer (score 2):

sorry,

i don't think php is the solution here, php can't force your ms access db to export itself to a csv file or more files

i had the same issue and I don't recommend trying to upload a ms access db directly in case it's big, use navicat instead

http://www.navicat.com/

**personal story related to your question**

here's my story, I had an ms acces db about 200 Mb in size, two tables with ~1000 rows and ~50000 rows and many other useful tables linked to these tables, I simply had to configure my connection to mysql server then upload that file, it didn't take long and my data was migrated without any data loss to mysql , bear in mind that you should pay attention to import forms and such, in case you'd like to update the existing database, bear in mind that you can set column mappings (old ms access db to new mysql structure)

Comment: So you did it with navicat??

Comment: of course, my job 1 year ago was to migrate an old ms access app to a web-based php/mysql app , data included